# Fork 3 children to run separate process each

Tags: fork, children

Most of the examples I have seen only Print "I am a child with PID" . I am trying to fork 3 children, each child running 3 different processes. each of the children are separate C programs. Hence, I need to call them using exec() after fork() but my problem is in the syntax and how to reference each child because all child processes have pid =0.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getmypid()` to get the pids in the children. The fork call returns 0 in the child processes:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
   $pid = pcntl_fork();
   if ($pid == -1) {
        die("Fork failed on loop #$i");
   } else if ($pid == 0) {
        $mypid = getmypid(); // executes in the children
        exec(... whatever this child has to run ...);
   } else {
        ... executes in the parent
   }
}
```

Note that this in PHP, but the basic mechanics remain the same in pretty much any language that does fork().

---

followup:

```
...
} else if ($pid == 0) {
    $mypid = getmypid();
    switch ($i) {
         case 0:
             exec(... app #1 ...)
         case 1:
             exec(... app #2 ...)
         case 2:
             exec(... app #3 ...)
    }
} ...
```

Is how you'd start up your 3 apps. At the moment the parent script calls fork(), each child will end up with a different $i, so you can determine which child you're in by the value of $i.

Comment: Thanks! Here is an extension. I am really trying to work my brain in understanding this concept. The parent process forks 3 processes, each of which should run separate code which are executables from separate C programs. And these processes should run simultaneously. Parent waits for any one to terminate. so, would there be 3 sets of lines $mypid = getpid(); exec( CHILD1); $mypid=getpid(); exec(CHILD2)  and so on???

Comment: I may have not been clear when I asked my question. I apologize. I do not want to switch between children. I want my parent to create 3 children and all three run at the same time. 2 of those children are basically infinite loops and one child reads characters from a file. When any one of the children terminates, until then parent waits. Hence, when the third child completes, Parent moves on even though the other 2 never terminate. The question in your example is how does "i" work to refer to child?

Comment: Think of fork() as a perfect photocopier. The only way to tell which is the original process and which is the child is by looking at which paper tray (the return value of fork()) the sheet came out in. If you're the parent, you just continue on with the main for() loop and fire up another fork (or exit the loop). if you're the child, then you figure out if you're the first/second/third child, and exec() the appropriate process. All three children will be running at the same time, each with its own pid, each being a child of the original process.